# Pagination vue data in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to get paginate works on my data in `vue.js` I found package for it ([gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination](https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination)) and install it but it doesn't work, I think I did everything in documentation but somehow it won't work,

`controller`

```
$projects = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

`vue template`

```
<pagination :data="projects" @pagination-change-page="load"></pagination>
```

`component script`

```
import pagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination';  //added here
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                projects: []
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.load()
        },
        methods: {
            load: function(page = 1) { //added here
                axios.get('/api/projects?page=' + page) //added here
                .then(
                    response => {
                        this.projects =  (response.data);
                    }     
                )
                .catch(function (error) {
                    this.errors.push(error);
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

## Error

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <pagination> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

## Question

1. Did I do something wrong? How to fix this?

## UPDATE

`controller`

```
public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return $projects->map(function($project) {
            $data = collect($project);
            $data->put('owner', $project->user);
            return $data->all();
        });
    }
```

PS: the reason I didn't return my data like:

```
return response()->json([
  "projects" => $projects,
], 200);
```

was to add project user to the results.

## Update 2

I have made some changes in my controller and script so I can get my data as json instead of array now, but still i cannot get pagination:

how my data look like now:

```
{
    "projects":{
            "current_page":1,
            "data":[
                {
                    "id":38,"
                    user_id":1,
                    "title":"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww",
                    "slug":"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww",
                    "body":"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww",
                    "created_at":"2018-08-10 15:55:28",
                    "updated_at":"2018-08-10 15:55:28",
                    "user":{
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"admin",
                        "email":"admin@admin.com",
                        "created_at":"2018-08-02 10:57:47",
                        "updated_at":"2018-08-02 10:57:47",
                        "profile":{
                            "id":1,"
                            user_id":1,"
                            photo":"project-attachment-1533159133.png",
                            "created_at":"2018-08-02 10:57:48",
                            "updated_at":"2018-08-02 10:57:48"
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
}
```

`controller`

```
public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::orderby('id', 'desc')->with('user')->with('user.profile')->paginate(10);
        return response()->json([
            "projects" => $projects,
        ], 200);
    }
```

`component`

```
<script>
import pagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                projects: []
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.load()
        },
        components: {
            pagination
        },
        methods: {
            load: function(page = 1) {
                axios.get('/api/projects?page=' + page)
                .then(
                    response => {
                        this.projects =  (response.data.projects.data); //here has changed
                    }     
                )
                .catch(function (error) {
                    this.errors.push(error);
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to register the imported pagination component app.js**

```
import pagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination';

Vue.component('pagination', pagination);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the imported `pagination` component in the current component, i.e. add `components: { pagination }` to `export default`:

```
export default {
  ...,
  components: {
    pagination
  }
}
```

Comment: now i get `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array.`

Comment: As the error suggests, you may have defined the props `data` in `pagination` as `Object` but you are passing it an array when using it. You need to make the definition and the actual data passed down consistent.

Comment: well the `load` is array of my projects and i loop them by `<div class="row" v-for="project in projects" :key="project.slug">` how can I give it as object? (sorry newbie with vue)

Comment: Where does the loop happen, in the current component or in the `pagination` component? Maybe you mean `:data="project"`?

Comment: in my script i get array of data `mounted: function() {
            this.load()
        },
        methods: {
            load:` and then in template i loop it by `<div class="row" v-for="project in projects" :key="project.slug">`

Comment: How is `data` props defined in `pagination` component? Is it an array or object? You can check [Vue Props here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

Comment: i assume in here `<pagination :data="projects" @pagination-change-page="load"></pagination>` this part ` @pagination-change-page="load"`

Comment: Can you check **How is data props defined in pagination component**? According to the error, you have a type mismatch.

Comment: Read the github docs, the `data` must be an object with this format `{
 current_page: 1,
 data: [],
 from: 1,
 last_page: 1,
 next_page_url: null,
 per_page: 10,
 prev_page_url: null,
 to: 1,
 total: 0,
}` where `projects` should be the data array, I guess.

Comment: if that's the case i can see my data by visiting api route my data is covered by array is like: `[{"id":38,"user_id":1,"title":"www","slug":"www","body":"wwwwww".........` see starts with `[`

Comment: Yes, your api seems to return an array, and you need to convert it to a format that `pagination` component understands, i.e., the above format.

Comment: please wait i will share my controller.